# Find the points on an ellipse that are a minimum/maximum distance away from a given point

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

You are given an ellipse in parametric form

$ E(t) = C + E_1 \cos(t) + E_2 \sin(t) $

where $C$, $E_1$, $E_2$ are $2-$ or $3-$ dimensional vectors corresponding to an ellipse specified in two dimensions or three dimensions, respectively.  In addition, you're given a point $P_0$, and you want to find points $A$ and $B$ on the ellipse that are a minimum/maximum distance away from $P$

The context is finding the distance between any point in the plane and an ellipse, just as you would find the distance between a point and a line or a point and a plane.

Comment: Are E1,E2 perpendicular?

Comment: Perpendicular or not, what you do is find the extrema of the squared distance, $(  -P +C  + E_1 \cos t + E_2 \sin t ) \cdot (  -P +C  + E_1 \cos t + E_2 \sin t )  $  which expands in dot product terms.  All four named vectors are constant,...